# Ruby on Rails - Active Admin Strange Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

On Rails 4. I'm getting some strange errors when I try to load index pages in Active Admin. They were all working fine before, but suddenly I started getting this message (for this example I loaded my Categories index but it is happening for most of them):

```
NoMethodError in Admin::Categories#index
Showing c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-3fb7f03335b1/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `validators_on' for Ransack::Search:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):

  insert_tag renderer_for(:index)

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
config/initializers/form_builder.rb:12:in `label'
```

I did a search for that method name and it returned only this:

```
In form_builder.rb

if object.class.validators_on(method).map(&:class).include? ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator
      if options.class != Hash
        options = {:class => "required"}
      else
        options[:class] = ((options[:class] || "") + " required").split(" ").uniq.join(" ")
      end
    end
```

I can view the dashboard and individual row pages fine, but when I go to edit a record I get this:

```
TypeError in Admin::Categories#edit
Showing c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-3fb7f03335b1/app/views/active_admin/resource/edit.html.arb where line #1 raised:

no implicit conversion of String into Array
Extracted source (around line #1):

  insert_tag renderer_for(:edit)

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
config/initializers/form_builder.rb:16:in `label'
```

I have no idea what this means...would it be better to re-install Active Admin/regenerate its assets? Is that a safe thing to do? If so, how do I do that? Or, is there a simple fix to these error messages. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue and have a fix for you. The issue is that the very clever [initializer](http://blog.pothoven.net/2012/10/self-marking-required-fields-in-rails.html) that automatically adds a CSS `*` to required fields is not compatible with the Ransack search that ActiveAdmin uses. The solution is to check that the model `responds_to` the necessary method before invoking it:

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  # http://blog.pothoven.net/2012/10/self-marking-required-fields-in-rails.html
  alias_method :orig_label, :label

  # add a 'required' CSS class to the field label if the field is required
  def label(method, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
    if content_or_options && content_or_options.class == Hash
      options = content_or_options
    else
      content = content_or_options
    end

    options = add_required_class(options) if presence_required?(method)
    orig_label(method, content, options || {}, &block)
  end

  private

  def add_required_class(options)
    return { class: 'required' } unless options.class == Hash
    new_class = ((options[:class].to_s || '') + ' required')
      .split(' ').uniq.join(' ')
    options.merge!(class: new_class)
  end

  def presence_required?(method)
    object.class.respond_to?(:validators_on) &&
      object.class.validators_on(method).collect(&:class)
        .include?(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you dankohn for your change, which works for me using the latest github active_admin. Do you think you could submit a patch to the corresponding project?

Comment: I would but there's no project. The code above comes from the blog post referenced, and has not been packaged into a gem. ActiveAdmin changed a private method, and so do not need any patches.

Comment: Actually for me in a nearly new app with rails 4.2.3, ruby 2.2.2-p95 and activeadmin (1.0.0.pre2 557d143) I could not login as admin, because of this error. Have not find any open issues, only your solution.

Answer (score 1):

AA works with Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.1, however, you have to take AA from the master branch at Github. Please note that AA switched from the "meta_search" gem to "ransack" which is **not** API-compatible - so some things are sure to break.

Maybe you use custom filters? I had your kind of errors due to custom filters based on scopes since "ransack" does not feature anything like `search_method` from "meta_search". Here's how I work around this, just in case:

- https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/345
- https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/288

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. My Gemfile IS set to take AA from the master branch at Github. Everything was working fine before, but now it is suddenly not for some reason. I do not think it is my filters (deleting all filter code kept the same error message). Do you know how to reinstall Active Admin? Is it safe to do that?

Comment: To my knowledge, the AA generator only creates the migration necessary for the admin comments. In other words, I don't think re-installing AA will help. Unless of course you've tampered with the gem code directly in which case I'd zap it and then pull it anew with `bundle install`.

Comment: I don't believe I tampered with the gem directly, but I did uninstall the gem and then re-installed and that did not seem to help. Don't know what else to try short of starting the project over.

Comment: Maybe the release of AA you're on is broken. Or ransack is the problem. The following versions work for me: active_admin-b951fde3f1e8 and ransack-b783c3c47bb9 (this release is **not** from hackery, but glebm/ransack, branch search_scopes).